# Visual Studio 2013 hide code block lines, indicators

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image: screenshot of editor in Visual Studio 2013]

Recently upgraded to VS 2013 which is great but I can't work out how to turn off the code block indicators. I've looked under Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Text Editor but I can't seem to find it. I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

Comment: is this not a extension ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you have the `Productivity Power Tools`extension installed.

To turn of the blue lines go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Turn Extensions On/Off
```

and turn off `Structure Visualizer` which should be the option third from the bottom.

Comment: On my VS2013, `Structure Visualizer` is `ON` and I haven't these lines.

Comment: @Xaruth That's odd. Changing this option is what shows/hides the guide lines for me. Maybe you turned off "Show code structure in the editor" in the Structure Visualizer options under "other extensions" in the same place (Prod Pow Tools)?

Comment: @jpw that's it. In `Other Extensions`, the options was disabled.